# MS SQL 2016 won't install. Claims the minimum requirements not met, but they are

Tags: sql-server

I have many years in IT mostly network and security, but the server side IS new to me. This IS my first rodeo. I am trying to mimic an existing production environment so I may practice and get to know things as we plan for server upgrades coming up. I am trying to install SQL Express 2016. I get the error that this device does not meet the minimum requirements. I have followed the link to Microsoft and carefully gone down the list, but not finding anything that stands out as the problem. 
*I am running in VMware Win Server 2008 R2 SP1 64bit and all required/suggested 162 updates have been installed
*I exceed the min specs with having 20GB space free, 2GB RAM, 4GHz, NTFS, .NET 4.6 installed...

Any suggestions how to narrow it down better?

I have not registered for the Evaluation, because this is Express and I thought I could run it free indefinitely. It is also in a virtual environment.

I find it funny that Microsoft tells you to "Spin up a Virtual Machine with SQL Server 2016 already installed." DUH! I would not be here if I could do that.

Comment: Unless i recall incorrectly (and I'm confident I'm not) SQL Server 2016 needs to be installed on Windows Server 2012+ or Windows 8+. Windows Server 2008/Windows 7 isn't a valid operating system; hence it doesn't meet the requirements as you're using an unsupported OS for the Service.

Comment: The minimum requirements are *clearly* not met. The earliest supported version is Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8. This is *clearly* indicated in the download pages. Win2K8R2 is no longer supported. Why do you try to use an 8-years old OS anyway? And why an *older* version of SQL Server?

Comment: The [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54284) specifies : `Supported Operating System : 
Windows 10 , Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016`

Comment: As for `Spin up a Virtual Machine with SQL Server 2016 already installed` it means that you can start an Azure VM with SQL Server already installed. `Have an Azure account? Then go Here to spin up a Virtual Machine with SQL Server 2016 SP1 already installed.`

Comment: As I had said, I was trying to mimic our existing environment to better understand how to prepare for future upgrades. I have since learned we are running SQL 2008 R2 on WS 2008 R2. I had been told we were SQL 2016 on WS 2008 R2 hence my question. All of this to be upgraded. I am just staging a virtual environment to learn what will need to be done.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Server 2008 isn't a supported OS by SQl Server 2016. A full list of supported OS's can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server#TOP_Principal

You'll note the oldest version of Windows supported by SQL Server 2016 is Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8.

Comment: The oldest supported Windows versions in *general* are Server 2012 and Windows 8.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos depends what you mean by supported. Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 are still under extended support. Windows 8, however, isn't supported anymore (at all I believe). To be supported you need to be using Windows 8.1; so you're not quite accurate. :)

Comment: there's no "depends" here. Extended support means no new features or even fixes apart from security fixes, no requirement for other products to support the OS. For all intents and purposes, except a PM trying to refuse an upgrade, it's accurate. Win 2k8 is the server version of the Vista wave anyway. Win2k8R2 was the one that came alongside Windows 7